How to create a Group and SharePoint Site in an Administrative Unit using Graph API?
If I try to create a Group in an Administrative Unit, there is no SharePoint Site created for that group. It actually doesn't matter, if I create the group on the Entry ID site or using the Graph API. If I create a Group normally (outside the Administrative Unit), a SharePoint Site is created.
Do I need to add some additional parameter to the request or is there some hidden setting on the Administrative Unit? Or is it just not possible to create a Group with SharePoint Site in an Administrative Unit?
I know I could create the group and SharePoint Site normally and then add the group to the administrative unit, but that either requires AdministrativeUnit.ReadWrite.All application permission or Privileged Role Administrator user role. We would like to avoid both of those for security resons.
Here are the documentations I followed:
Add a member to an administrative unit
Create group
Permissions of my app registration:

AdministrativeUnit.Read.All (Application)
Group.Create (Application)

Create Group Request:
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups

{
    "displayName": "Test 001",
    "mailEnabled": false,
    "mailNickname": "test-001",
    "securityEnabled": true,
    "groupTypes": [
        "Unified"
    ],
    "owners@odata.bind": [
        "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}"
    ]
}

Result: The group is created together with a SharePoint site. To add it to the administrative unit additional permissions are required.
Create Group in Administrative Unit Request:
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directory/administrativeUnits/{id}/members

{
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.group",
    "displayName": "Test 002",
    "mailEnabled": false,
    "mailNickname": "test-002",
    "securityEnabled": true,
    "groupTypes": [
        "Unified"
    ],
    "owners@odata.bind": [
        "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}"
    ]
}

Result: The group is created in the administrative unit, but no SharePoint site is created.
